# FIND shell command does not work when executing with .NET Process.Start with redirected output streams

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file, process.start

I have problem with windows shell find command in bat file. Output of the find command is always empty. Bat file is executed using .NET's `Process.Start` method in C#. I use output stream redirection. What I want to do:

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("c:\test.bat")
{
  CreateNoWindow = true,                        
  UseShellExecute = false,
  RedirectStandardOutput = true,
  RedirectStandardError = true
};
Process testProcess = new Process();
testProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
testProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(testProcess_OutputDataReceived);
testProcess.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(testProcess_ErrorDataReceived);                    
testProcess.StartInfo = processInfo;
testProcess.Start();
```

Batch file (c:\test.bat) contains find command with redirection to the output file:

```
find /I "TestString" "c:\TestInput.xml" > output.txt
```

Redirection of the outputStream works fine, but the content of the output.txt is empty (File size is 0B). When I execute same batch command, output.txt contains found string occurences. Is it possible to get find command in batch file work with `Process.Start` and output streams redirected?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How do you retrieve the output so you get an empty result?

Comment: Please show is a **complete** code sample that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't start a batch file directly through the Process class when ShellExecute is disabled (and you can't redirect with ShellExecute enabled). This is because batch files are not really executable in a sense, it is an artificial construct in explorer.

Anyway what you can do to fix it is to use cmd.exe directly, e.g. change your ProcessStartInfo to something like:

```
new ProcessStartInfo(@"cmd.exe", @"/c C:\test.bat")
```

And also make sure you wait for the command to exit.

Answer (score 0):

Without more info, it's impossible to say what problem you're having. However, the following works:

```
var find = new Process();
var psi = find.StartInfo;
psi.FileName = "find.exe";
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

// remember to quote the search string argument
psi.Arguments = "\"quick\" xyzzy.txt";

find.Start();

string rslt = find.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

find.WaitForExit();

Console.WriteLine("Result = {0}", rslt);

Console.WriteLine();
Console.Write("Press Enter:");
Console.ReadLine();
return 0;
```

Running that against my sample file gives the same results as I get when I run `find` from the command line using the same arguments.

The thing that might trip you up here is that the `find` command requires the search string argument to be quoted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have edited my previous post and I added better description of my problem.